# Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option one error found というエラー

Tags: macos, scala, encoding

パスが、以下になっています。

```
which scala
/usr/local/bin/scala
```

## ソース

```scala
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.awt.Color

/**
 * マンデルブロート集合を表示する。
 */
object Mandelbrot {
    /**
     * 画像を作成する。
     */
    def createImage(mx:Double, my:Double, zoom:Double, maxCount:Int):BufferedImage = {
        var image = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)
        for (y <- 0 until image.getHeight) {
            for (x <- 0 until image.getWidth) {
                val cx = mx + (x-image.getWidth  / 2) / zoom
                val cy = my - (y-image.getHeight / 2) / zoom
                val count = calcMandelbrot(cx, cy, maxCount)
                if (count != -1) {
                    val color = Color.HSBtoRGB(count/100.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
                    image.setRGB(x, y, color)
                }
                else {
                    image.setRGB(x, y, 0)   // BLACK
                }
            }
        }
        image
    }
    /**
     * マンデルブロートの各点において、z^2 > 4 になるまでの回数を計算する。
     * maxCount回を超えると-1を返す。
     */
    def calcMandelbrot(cx:Double, cy:Double, maxCount:Int):Int = {
        var zx = 0.0
        var zy = 0.0
        for (i <- 0 until maxCount) {
            val sx = zx * zx
            val sy = zy * zy
            if ((sx + sy) >= 4.0)
                return i
            zy = 2.0 * zx * zy + cy
            zx = sx - sy + cx
        }
        -1
    }
}

import scala.swing.{SwingApplication,MainFrame,Label,Alignment}
import java.io.File
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import javax.swing.ImageIcon

object MandelbrotTest extends SwingApplication {
    val image = Mandelbrot.createImage(-0.745428, 0.113009, 100, 100)
//  val image = Mandelbrot.createImage(-0.745428, 0.113009, 1000, 100)
//  val image = Mandelbrot.createImage(-0.745428, 0.113009, 10000, 500)
//  val image = Mandelbrot.createImage(-0.745428, 0.113009, 100000, 1000)
//  val image = Mandelbrot.createImage(-0.745428, 0.113009, 1000000, 1000)
//  val image = Mandelbrot.createImage(-0.745428, 0.113009, 10000000, 1500)
//  val image = Mandelbrot.createImage(-0.745428, 0.113009, 100000000, 2000)
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("MandelbrotSet0.png"))

    def startup(args: Array[String]) {
        val top = new MainFrame {
            title = "Mandelbrot Set"
            iconImage = ImageIO.read(new File("MandelbrotSet250x250.png"))
            contents = new Label("", new ImageIcon(image), Alignment.Center)
            pack()
            visible = true
        }
    }
}
```

コンパイルすると、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
scalac -encoding Shift_JIS /Users/akane/Desktop/Hello.scala
error: IO error while decoding /Users/akane/Desktop/Hello.scala with Shift_JIS: MALFORMED[1]
Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
one error found
```

何を直せばいいのでしょうか？

mi editor UTF-8 LF(Mac/Unix) です。

Comment: `-encoding Shift_JIS` を指定なさっているのは何故でしょうか？

Comment: UTF-8でも、上手くいかなかった。

Comment: このオプションが無くても一言一句同じエラーが出るのでしょうか？

Comment: scalac /Users/akane/Desktop/Mandelbrot.scala
error: IO error while decoding /Users/akane/Desktop/Mandelbrot.scala with UTF-8: /Users/akane/Desktop/Mandelbrot.scala (No such file or directory)
Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
one error found

Comment: 出ました。酷すぎる。解説サイトが、見つからない。

Comment: "No such file or directory" は「このファイルが見つかりません」というエラーです。典型的にはファイル名が間違っているときに出ます。そして、質問文に元々書かれていた `-encoding Shift_JIS` 付きのものでは Hello.scala をコンパイルしようとしていますが、今回のものでは Mandelbrot.scala をコンパイルしようとしているように見えます。本当のファイル名はどちらですか？

Answer (score 0):

ソースコードをUTF-8で保存していれば、特にencodingの指定は不要ですよ。